# Обработка разнотипных данных в void* массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, address

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему это не работает и как сделать чтобы работало?
Хотелось получить список с адресами и по ним вызывать данные разного типа.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()

{    
    int a = 5;
    char b = 'a';
    string c = "abc";

    void *arr[3]={&a, &b, &c};

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

        cout << *arr[i]<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "почему не работает"? Унарный `*` неприменим к указателю типа `void *`.

Comment: cout << arr[i]<< endl;    ну вот таким же образом я получаю адреса на участки памяти, а значит их можно куда-то передать и вызвать так ведь ?

Comment: @Oleksii: Для того, чтобы правильно интерпретировать "участок памяти", мало знать с какого места в памяти этот участок начинается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку `void*` - указатель на ничто :), что вы собираетесь вывести как `*arr[i]`? Откуда компилятор может знать, что за адрес там лежит и как трактовать данные по этому адресу?...

Вот так можно:

```
cout << *(int*)a[0] << endl;
cout << *(char*)a[1] << endl;
cout << *(string*)a[2] << endl;
```

Comment: а есть возможность как-то организовать для утиной типизации,  я ведь могу не знать что там конкретно по адресу ?

Comment: Тогда где-то нужно хранить еще и тип. Только учтите, что разных типов теоретически бесконечно много :) D принципе, можно посмотреть сюда - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant - но это решение вряд ли вам понравится. Оно непростое...

Comment: Спасибо, мысль понял :)

Comment: Скорее, `void*` указатель на что угодно, чем на ничто.

Comment: @alexolut На нечто :)